# How to Plot a Power Curve

Tags: python, math, statistics

How can I plot a power curve where I have one-sided binomial test H0: p= 0.7 , Ha: p>0.7 at a significance level  = 0.05 and a sample size of n= 20 (plotting the curve for x = 0.7,0.71,0.72...1)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may refer to the Python Scipy functions and then use Matplotlib for the data plotting.

[Scipy.binomial test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom_test.html#scipy.stats.binom_test)

[Scipy Binomial distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html)

[Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/)